# Matrix Generation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of strings as follows (The size of the array may change)

```
A
B
C
D
```

I need to generate a matrix as follows which contains all the possible combinations.

```
A B C D
A B D C
A C B D
A C D B
A D B C
A D C B
B C D A
B C A D
B D C A
B D A C
B A B D
B A D B
C D A B
C D B A
C A B D
C A D B
C B D A
C B A D
D A B C
D A C B
D B A C
D B C A
D C A B
D C B A
```

Which is the best algorithm that can be used to generate this array?

Comment: Can you have *duplicates* among the strings? E.g. `A B A D` (Note that `A` appears twice and so we have fewer distinct permutations)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for all the [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation), here is an example using the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) module in python:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> [p for p in permutations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])]
[
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    ['A', 'B', 'D', 'C'],
    ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'],
    ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B'],
    ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C'],
    ['A', 'D', 'C', 'B'],
    ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'],
    ['B', 'A', 'D', 'C'],
    ['B', 'C', 'A', 'D'],
    ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A'],
    ['B', 'D', 'A', 'C'],
    ['B', 'D', 'C', 'A'],
    ['C', 'A', 'B', 'D'],
    ['C', 'A', 'D', 'B'],
    ['C', 'B', 'A', 'D'],
    ['C', 'B', 'D', 'A'],
    ['C', 'D', 'A', 'B'],
    ['C', 'D', 'B', 'A'],
    ['D', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'A', 'C', 'B'],
    ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'],
    ['D', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
    ['D', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
    ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
]
```

***Indentation modified manually for easier visualization that output matches desired output.***

Answer (score 0):

Although the existing answer is obviously correct, one may think that you want a code that creates the permutations itself, without library functions.

This is one example of a simple recursive solutions, also in Python:

```
def permu(ls, lvl=1):
    if len(ls) < 2:
        return [ls]
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        tail = ls[:]
        head = tail.pop(i)
        for s in permu(tail, lvl+1):
            s.insert(0, head)
            ret.append(s)
    return ret
```

A better, iterative solution is given in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.permutations) as a rough equivalent of how the `permutations()` function actually works.

Keep in mind that the number of permutations is the factorial of `n`, so it will become very large even for relatively small values: `20!` amounts to 2432902008176640000